# Is it necessary to re-index documents after adding MappingCharFilterFactory in schema file?

Tags: search, solr

I am working on Solr search. I am indexing documents with diacritics to Solr. But the problem is that if I search the same word with no diacritics it does not return the result.

I have made the changes in my schema file as from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697009/remove-diacritics-at-index-time-into-solr)!

Changes that I have added in Schema file:

```
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
```

It gives me result.

I have index 10 million products to solr.
But my problem is that it is necessary to re-index all of the documents. Is there any solution for no need to re-index all documents?

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short ansawer is: Yes, it is necessary. The index will be inconsistent otherwise, as you'll have documents where the conversion has taken place, and documents where it hasn't.

The longer answer is: You can (sort of) work around the problem, although it will cost more when querying (as you want to move as much work as possible onto the indexing part, this might not be a good idea). You'd have to add a filter that creates all the different versions of the characters that could possibly have diacritics attached to them for a query, which can result in a large number of terms with and without diacritics.

Depending on the number of terms, it might be enough to generate a synonym word list for the most important words for now. Fetch all the terms from the database with diacritics, run a conversion on those terms and create a synonym word list from that. Use that to expand the queries to other versions of the same term with and without diacritics.

This is not an ideal situation, and you should probably focus on handling reindexing better instead, as it is something you might have to do on upgrades, other changes to your schema, etc.